USB/UART to Network Interface
I have a modem that works via a USB interface (read/write messages to FTDI) but, can I turn it into an actual network interface so I can interact to it via sockets (SOCK_DGRAM)? Perhaps there are other types of sockets that would work with it?

If it's connected to an FTDI chip, it speaks a serial port interface, and cannot emulate a USB network interface.
So, as with any modem, the point where the device that transports data becomes a network interface is in the modem driver / software running on your device.
You don't tell us what your modem does. It might simply not do a communication standard that does packet-style communications; then it's not sensible to represent it as such.
It might, however, actually be something that can transport e.g. IP packets. Then it's sensible, and then something probably already does that; that something, if your modem is a telephone modem, for example, might be software like pppd, or a kernel-mode driver.
So, you will actually have to read the documentation of your specific modem, and specifically say what kind of network you connect to.
